# LateInitializationError: Field 'email' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, validation, dart-null-safety

i am trying to get the text kept in the validator property in the TextFormField to show in the app but for some reason, it keeps keeps giving me the LateInitializationError: Field 'email' has not been initialized. even though i have initialized my email and password in the onChanged property.
Here is the code

```
class SellersLoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SellersLoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String routName = 'SellersLoginScreen';

  @override
  State<SellersLoginScreen> createState() => _SellersLoginScreenState();
}

class _SellersLoginScreenState extends State<SellersLoginScreen> {

   final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool passwordVisible = true;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   late String email;
   late String password;

   void loginSeller() async{
    try{
      if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password
      );
      }else{
        return snackBar('Please fields must not be empty', context);
      }
    }catch(e){
   return print(e);
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child:Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text('Sign in To Seller Account',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Typett',
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: (){},
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.person,
                              size: 35,
                              color: Colors.cyan,
                            )
                        )
                      ],
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        email = value;
                      },
                      validator: (value){
                        if(value!.isEmpty){
                          'please email address must not be empty';
                        }else{
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email',
                        hintText: 'Enter your Email',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        password = value;
                      },
                      validator: (value){
                        if(value!.isEmpty){
                          'please password field must not be empty';
                        }else{
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      obscureText: passwordVisible,                                    
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            onPressed: (){
                              setState(() {
                                passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                              });
                            },
                            icon: passwordVisible? Icon(                               
  
                              Icons.visibility,
                            ):Icon(Icons.visibility_off)
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        hintText: 'Enter your Password',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        loginSeller();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.cyan,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child:  Text('Login',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

perhaps there is something i am missing. i have tried replacing the late with an empty string but it still didnt work. help is very much needed

Comment: Is there any other place you are using `email`?

Comment: I used email in another page for the same purpose and it worked over there. needed the variable again and it didn't work

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error from the current snippet. Perhaps somewhere in this widget using `email` filed on widget tree

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
late String email;
```

to:

```
String? email;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   class SellersLoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const SellersLoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      static const String routName = 'SellersLoginScreen';
    
      @override
      State<SellersLoginScreen> createState() => _SellersLoginScreenState();
    }
    
    class _SellersLoginScreenState extends State<SellersLoginScreen> {
    
       final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      bool passwordVisible = true;
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
       late String email;
       late String password;
    
       void loginSeller() async{
        try{
          if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email, password: password
          );
          }else{
            return snackBar('Please fields must not be empty', context);
          }
        }catch(e){
       return print(e);
        }
      }
    
@override
void initState() {
  email = "";
  password="";
  super.initState();
}
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child:Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text('Sign in To Seller Account',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Typett',
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed: (){},
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.person,
                                  size: 35,
                                  color: Colors.cyan,
                                )
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          onChanged: (String value){
                            email = value;
                          },
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value!.isEmpty){
                              'please email address must not be empty';
                            }else{
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Email',
                            hintText: 'Enter your Email',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          onChanged: (String value){
                            password = value;
                          },
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value!.isEmpty){
                              'please password field must not be empty';
                            }else{
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                          obscureText: passwordVisible,                                    
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                onPressed: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: passwordVisible? Icon(                               
      
                                  Icons.visibility,
                                ):Icon(Icons.visibility_off)
                            ),
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            hintText: 'Enter your Password',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            loginSeller();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.cyan,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child:  Text('Login',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String? email;
```

and the `initState` to evaluate and set the value to the email variable.

Answer (score 0):

just write

```
String email = "";
String password = "";
```

instead of late keyword as it cannot be null and need to be initialized as well.